# How to enable per-command history in fzf?

Tags: terminal, fzf

In fzf, by default, CTRL-P and CTRL-N are bound to move up and down in the items list. How can I bound then to previous-history and next-history instead?

Comment: Since the accepted answer is about Vim fzf, maybe we should rename the title of this to reflect that the OP was asking about Vim fzf and not fzf?

Comment: The link in the answer goes to fzf.vim!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docks, check the [global options](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim#global-options):

```
" Enable per-command history.
" CTRL-N and CTRL-P will be automatically bound to next-history and
" previous-history instead of down and up. If you don't like the change,
" explicitly bind the keys to down and up in your $FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS.
let g:fzf_history_dir = '~/.local/share/fzf-history'
```

Comment: Has this been removed? There's nothing about it on the README you linked to.